# Testing angularjs directive with Karma and Jasmine - module is not defined

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to run a simple test on a directive I have built and I'm getting the following error every time:

```
ReferenceError: module is not defined in /root/node-workspace/tk-quick-form/test.js (line 4)
```

my karma.conf.js file (relevant content):

```
//...
files: [
  'angular.min.js',
  'tkQuickForm.js',
  'test.js'
],
//...
```

my test.js file:

```
describe('Testing quickForm', function() {
    var $compile, $rootScope;

    beforeEach(module('tkQuickForm')); //the error points to this line

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$compile_, _$rootScope_) {
        $compile = _$compile_;
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    }));

    it("Creates a simple form", function() {
        $rootScope.formStructure = [
            {
                fieldName: 'name',
                type: 'string'
            }
        ];
        var element = $compile("<div tk-quick-form='formStructure'></div>")($rootScope);

        $rootScope.$digest();
        expect(element.html()).toContain('<input id="name"');
    });
})
```

and this is the first few lines of the directive I'm testing:

```
angular.module('tkQuickForm', [])
.directive('tkQuickForm', ['$http', '$compile', formDirective]);

function formDirective($http, $compile) {
     //some code...
}
```

This is a first time for me working with Karma and Jasmine, so I might be missing something rather simple here, though I can't figure out exactly what.

Comment: Try including 'angular-mocks.js' in your karma.conf.js files. Include it right after 'angular.min.js'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For testing you should use ngMock module

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock

It allows you to inject and mock angular services.